# How to update Jquery UI Progress Bar

Tags: jquery

I have the following snippet :

```
<div class="progress" data-value="10" data-show-value="true"></div>
```

It's a progress bar that' i'm trying to refresh to show progress of a background process.

A live example of code can be found here : http://themes.vivantdesigns.com/vpanel/demo/styles

I'd like to update the 'data-value' attribute; i'm using :

```
<script>
$(".progress").everyTime(1000,function(i) {
    var val = $(this).attr('data-value');
    val = val + 20;
    $(this).attr('data-value', val);
});
</script>
```

"val" is 10, right but it doesn't change the attribute. Any idea why ?

Comment: `$( this ).data( 'data-value', function ( i, val ) { return val + 20; });`

Comment: What is `everyTime`?  Is that a plugin?

Comment: This works for me, just fine.  Well, except that the new value becomes `1020` and not `30`.  You're gonna want to convert the value to an int: `var val = parseInt($(this).attr('data-value'), 10);`

Comment: @myself Looks good, but jQuery didn't implement this (yet) (the second argument cannot be a handler) `-.-`

Comment: *but it doesn't change the attribute* ... how are you verifying this? The HTML *source* is never changed.

Comment: @rocket yes, timers plugin http://plugins.jquery.com/project/timers

Comment: @Disco: You should mention that in the question.  You should also mention that you're making a progress bar, and trying to update its display.

Comment: @Rocket : right, updated question.

Comment: @Disco: How are you making the progress bar?  What plugin (if any) are you using?

Comment: @Disco: I don't see any code for the progress bar, just what one looks like.  Can you post the code you use to make the progress bar?

Comment: @Rocket : well if you check out the site i posted, there's only this div .progress i'm trying to update live

Comment: @Disco: I see the progress bar, but that's it.  No code.  That's not a plugin, that's just a theme.  Is that a jQuery UI theme, or a theme for another plugin?

Comment: @Disco: It seems that this is a theme for jQuery UI.  The docs for the progress bar are here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/progressbar/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".progress").everyTime("1s", function(i) {   
    $(this).attr('data-value', parseInt($(this).attr('data-value'), 10) + 20);   
});      
</script>
```

**EDIT**

If you're looking to create a progress bar, you can check out the [jQuery Progressbar](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Progressbar):

```
$("#progressbar").progressbar({ value: ( STORED_DATA / TOTAL_DATA) });
```

**EDIT**

If you're looking to display a progress bar in HTML5, it might be simpler to just use the `Progress` tag:

```
$("#progressBar").everyTime("1s", function(i){
    $(this).attr("value", parseInt($(this).attr("value"), 10) + 10);
});

<progress id="progressBar" max="100" value="0" />
```

Comment: HTML5 doesn't need the script type.

Comment: @James : well, the attribute is set correctly but the progress bar doesn't 'refresh'

Comment: You forgot the radix for `parseInt`. `parseInt($(this).attr('data-value'), 10)`.  Also `everyTime` can take a string or an int as the interval.

Comment: @Disco: You're making a progress bar?  That's a different problem.  How are you making a progress bar?

Comment: Can you revise your question to show how you're trying to update the progress bar?

Comment: @Disco: What progress bar plugin (if any) are you using?

Comment: I'm confused... how is updating the `data-value` attribute supposed to display progress?

Comment: @Rocket : here -> http://themes.vivantdesigns.com/vpanel/demo/styles
updated question.

Comment: @James : well if i change the data-value, the progress bar displays correctly.

Comment: Are you using a plugin or something? I'm sorry, it's just tough to understand how this is supposed to work.

Comment: @Disco: There's no info/code there, just a theme.  What's this a theme for?  Is it for jQuery UI?

Comment: @Disco: I would suggest taking a few minutes to revise your question so we have enough information to answer the question.

Comment: Well; it's not a plugin; it's just a styled div. What else can I say

Comment: @JamesJohnson: After doing some research I've figured out the theme is a jQuery UI theme.

Comment: @Disco: You can't just copy the div, change it's `data-value` attribute, and expect it to magically update.  It doesn't work that way.  This is a theme for jQuery UI.  You need to load jQuery UI and set up the progress bar.  Check out the docs here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/progressbar/

Comment: @JamesJohnson: HTML 5 has a `progress` tag?  That's awesome, I didn't know that. :-)

Comment: Neither did I until a few days ago ;) It would appear that HTML5 has everything and the kitchen sink.

Comment: @James : Works now ! Thanks for downvoting my question REALLY appreciate ... you know, we're not ALL Jquery Experts; I didn't even knew it was part of the UI; anyway thanks for the one who has downvoted me; really encouraging me to ask questions again

Comment: @JamesJohnson: [Not all browsers](http://thebrowsereview.com/2011/the-progress-html5-tag-browser-support/) *cough* Internet Explorer *cough* support the `progress` tag, though.

Comment: I didn't downvote your question... I was trying to stay on your good side ;)

Comment: I just upvoted the question to encourage you to ask more questions.

Comment: @Disco: You didn't get downvoted for not being a "jQuery expert".  You got downvoted for not including enough detail in your question.  When this was first asked, we had no idea what you were trying to do.  You should try to add as much detail as possible to the question when you ask it.